# Not expected N+1 queries with Hibernate Projection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Just face the N+1 query problem with such Spring Data repository

```java
public interface ToDoRepository extends CrudRepository<ToDo, Long> {

    @Query("select new com.package.repr.ToDoRepr(t) from ToDo t " +
            "where t.user.id = :userId")
    List<ToDoRepr> findToDosByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);
}
```

I see in the logs one such query

> Hibernate: 
>       select
>           todo0_.id as col_0_0_ 
>       from
>           todos todo0_ 
>       where
>           todo0_.user_id=?
>   ]

And N such queries

> Hibernate: 
>       select
>           todo0_.id as id1_0_0_,
>           todo0_.description as descript2_0_0_,
>           todo0_.target_date as target_d3_0_0_,
>           todo0_.user_id as user_id4_0_0_,
>           user1_.id as id1_1_1_,
>           user1_.password as password2_1_1_,
>           user1_.username as username3_1_1_ 
>       from
>           todos todo0_ 
>       left outer join
>           users user1_ 
>               on todo0_.user_id=user1_.id 
>       where
>           todo0_.id=?

ToDoRepr is a simple POJO. With constructor which accepts ToDo entity as a parameter.

Here are two JPA entities I use in this query

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "todos")
public class ToDo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column
    private LocalDate targetDate;

    // geters, setters, etc.
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<ToDo> todos;

    // geters, setters, etc.
}
```

UPD. It possible to resolve the problem by that query but why it's not working with constructor which accepts entity as a parameter?

```
public interface ToDoRepository extends CrudRepository<ToDo, Long> {

    @Query("select new com.package.repr.ToDoRepr(t.id, t.description, t.user.username, t.targetDate) " +
            "from ToDo t " +
            "where t.user.id = :userId")
    List<ToDoRepr> findToDosByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);
}
```

Comment: You have `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user" ...)` which makes the relationship bi-directional. Do you need this relationship mapped in `User` class? Removing `todos` from `User` would probably avoid problems like that.

Comment: Anyway, that's change nothing, related to my question. Also without mapped by Hibernate creates the third table which is not needed for my case.

Answer (score 2):

> This is a very common question so I created the article [Eliminate Spring Hibernate N+1 queries](https://yannbriancon.com/blog/eliminate-hibernate-n-plus-one-queries/) detailing the solutions

The best practice with Hibernate is to **define all associations as Lazy** to avoid fetching it when you don't need it.
For more reasons, check Vlad Mihalcea's article https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/

For fixing your issue, in your class ToDo, you should **define the ManyToOne as Lazy**:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "todos")
public class ToDo {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    ...

    // geters, setters, etc.
}
```

If you need to access the user in your ToDoRepr, it will not be loaded by default so you need to add it to your query:

- JPQL, **use JOIN FETCH**:

```java
public interface ToDoRepository extends CrudRepository<ToDo, Long> {

    @Query("select new com.package.repr.ToDoRepr(t) " +
            "from ToDo t " +
            "inner join fetch t.user " +
            "where t.user.id = :userId")
    List<ToDoRepr> findToDosByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);
}
```

- JPA, **use EntityGraph**:

```java
public interface ToDoRepository extends CrudRepository<ToDo, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"user"})
    List<ToDoRepr> findToDosByUser_Id(Long userId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to collect here some workaround about this my own question. There is a simple solution without explicit JPQL queries. Spring Data JPA can treat any POJO with proper getters and setters as a projection.

Just that works perfectly for me

```
public interface ToDoRepository extends CrudRepository<ToDo, Long> {

    List<ToDoRepr> findToDosByUser_Id(Long userId);
}
```